# Why jQuery.append(new Array(3).fill($('<div>',{text:'hello'}))) appends only one item?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have this code:

```
const a = [
  $('<div>', { text:'hello' }), 
  $('<div>', { text:'hello' }),
  $('<div>', { text:'hello' })
]
$('#a').append(a)
```

I get the expected result, 3 new items are appended to `#a`.

However when I create the array this way I get only 1 item appended to `#b`

```
const b = new Array(3).fill($('<div>', { text: 'hello' })) 
$('#b').append(b)
```

In the console output the 2 arrays seem identical. To play around: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/fokupaguso/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
const a=[
  $('<div>',{text:'hello'}),
  $('<div>',{text:'hello'}),
  $('<div>',{text:'hello'})]
const b=new Array(3).fill($('<div>',{text:'hello'}))
$('#a').append(a)
$('#b').append(b)
console.log('Array.isArray(a): '+Array.isArray(a)+' a.length: '+a.length)
console.log('Array.isArray(b): '+Array.isArray(b)+' b.length: '+b.length)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Append</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <div id="a" style="background:aqua;"></div>
  <div id="b" style="background:silver;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works with `.fill('<div>hello</div>')`, so I would assume it's something to do with the references to the created elements in the array being treated as a single instance by `append()`.

Comment: @marekful here you go: https://jsbin.com/zuquciyuga/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fill the array with three times the same object reference, which means jQuery will only add it once. The second and third time it will consider it already added and not do anything.

Change:

```
const b = new Array(3).fill($('<div>', { text: 'hello' }))
```

to:

```
const b = Array.from(Array(3), () => $('<div>', { text: 'hello' }))
```

Now you have a callback that is executed three times and thus calls `$(...)` three times instead of once, creating three separate instances.